# Deep watch arbitriary JSON keys with computed properties in Ember

Tags: json, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have a use case where a Model has a JSON attribute used for arbitrary configurations: `configuration: DS.attr()`.

I have a `configurationService` (initialized in every component/route/controller/…) with computed properties for easily retrieving this configurations throughout the application

Since the JSON configurations are quite large & have variable depth **I can’t have a computed property for every single one**.

Unfortunately, **being the Service a singleton** computed properties don’t detect the changes in the JSON keys (a.k.a. deep watch).
**I there a way to force deep watching a JSON attribute**?

Example:

services/configuration.js:

```
// These below can also be computed.alias, same effect

configuration: Ember.computed(‘account.configuration', function() {
  // account is set at application’s route:
  //   set(this, ‘configurationService.account', account);
  return this.get(‘account.configuration’); 
}),
profile: Ember.computed('configuration.profile', function() {
  return this.get('configuration.profile');
}),
```

any/given/component.js:

```
configurationService: Ember.inject.service(‘configuration’),
…
// These won’t detect changes
randomConfig: Ember.computed.alias(’configurationService.profile.foo.bar.randomConfig')
```

Considering the configuration object was: `{configuration: {profile: {foo: {bar: {randomConfig: false}}}}}`, if I somehow change `randomConfig` to `true`, **it won’t be detected**

- Note: I considered https://github.com/lytics/ember-data-model-fragments but discarded it since it’s too verbose, the issue is that our `configuration` object can become quite large and deep, dynamic  & unpredictable
- I tried `computed.alias` as well with no success.

Any hints or alternatives would be appreciated :)

**UPDATE:**
I tried with an `object` Transform ([as suggested in Slack](https://embercommunity.slack.com/archives/-help/p1475469704021085)) and it doesn’t observe it deeply: https://gist.github.com/benoror/272f0ae893f80276ac1553ae048e6b20#file-object-js

Comment: Can you give us a sense for the expected size and structure of the configuration hash? You might want to implement your own method for setting configuration values that sends custom events to anyone observing the configuration property. The more information you provide about how it's used, the easier it will be to suggest an approach.

Comment: Hey @maffews, the `configuration` hash comes from the backend, and can be dynamic & unpredictable, I can't predict the final form, as the app will dynamically adapt depending on its contents.

Comment: runspired suggested used a Transform: https://embercommunity.slack.com/archives/-help/p1475469704021085

Comment: My solution so far is to avoid computed properties, thus the service altogether, and access the data directly

Answer (score 0):

You need to transform the plain JS-Object to an Ember-Object, and so for its child objects:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import DS from 'ember-data';

function emberify(obj) {
  if(obj instanceof Array) {
    return Ember.A(obj.map(i => emberify(i)));
  } else if (obj instanceof Object) {
    return Ember.Object.create(Object.keys(obj)
      .reduce((hash, key) => {
        hash[key] = emberify(obj[key]);
      }, {}));
  }
}

export default DS.Transform.extend({
  deserialize: function(value) {
    return emberify(obj);
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried with `Ember.object.create`, but deep-watch still doesn't work: https://gist.github.com/benoror/272f0ae893f80276ac1553ae048e6b20#file-object-js

Comment: @BenOrozco you only create an `Ember.Object` for the top level object, not deeply nested.